# How do I get the specific gameobject clicked on out of many using that script in Unit2d C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onmousedown

I have a bunch of gameobjects with the following script attached.  I am trying to get the specific gameobject clicked on so I can move it.  The debug fundtion works fine, but I can't access the object to move it.

```c#
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    Debug.Log(senatorName + " is in chamber " + inChamber);
    GameObject disSenator = GameObject.Find(senatorName);
    newPos = new Vector3(0, 0, -2);
    disSenator.MoveSenator(newPos);
}

public void MoveSenator(Vector3 newPos)
{
    senator.transform.position = newPos;
}
```

The script objects to the line
`disSenator.MoveSenator(newPos);`

I've tried a bunch of other methods and nothing works even when I get no errors.

Thanks in advance for answering a newbie question.

Comment: What do you mean by "The script objects to the line "disSenator.MoveSenator(newPos);""?

Comment: Sorry.  I mean I get an error as follows:Type `UnityEngine.GameObject' does not contain a definition for `MoveSenator' and no extension method `MoveSenator' of type `UnityEngine.GameObject' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you inherit from MonoBehavior, this should work, for each object the mouse is clicking on, that has this script:

```c#
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    Debug.Log(senatorName + " is in chamber " + inChamber);
    newPos = new Vector3(0, 0, -2);
    transform.position = newPos;            
}
```

Comment: OK the solution works, but when I try to expand the code to choose and calc the new position, the code looses focus during the function call & I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". The new code goes to the chamber script chSc:

Comment: There seems to be a lot of answers here. In some cases you say it works, but have another problem, and in others you indicate that MonoBehavior is not relevant here.
Can you please post the code that currently fails, and explain where it fails?

Answer (score 0):

Use MonoBehavior's `gameObject` property to access the object that the script is attached to: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html

Answer (score 0):

HORRAY!!!  I stumbled onto the solution while flailing in vain.  The trick is to get the Rigidbody rather than the GameObject.  Here's the code that works:

```css
 public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log(senatorName + " is in chamber " + inChamber);
        rbSenator = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        string newChamber = chooseMove(inChamber);
        newPos = actMove(newChamber);
        inChamber = newChamber;
        rbSenator.transform.position = newPos;
        Debug.Log(senatorName + " is in chamber " + inChamber);
    }
```